# split with specific comma not within quotes in python

Tags: python, split

i have this string and i want to split it with ","

```
x = 'a, b, c , d , "x,x,2" , hi'
x.split(',')
```

here is my real string

```
x = 'Outward   ,Supply , ,Tax Invoice ,IN9195212470,31/12/2019,VPS AGRO & AUTO PVT LTD ,311954,06AAACV9344F1ZA ,"VILLAGE KHANPUR KOLIAN, N.H. 1 ",6 K.M. FRO,KURUKSHETRA   ,HARYANA ,136131,VPS AGRO & AUTO PVT LTD ,311954,"VILLAGE KHANPUR KOLIAN, N.H. 1",6 K.M. FRO,KURUKSHETRA                             ,HARYANA             ,136131,503675,SM VAL. GENUINE DIESEL ENG. OIL 1/9 L   ,27101980,360,LTR,58204.04,9,5238.36,9,5238.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,68680.76,                    ,                    ,                              ,          ,          ,,               ,          ,06AAACW0287A1ZR   ,VALVOLINE CUMMINS PVT LTD-AMBALA        ,"KHASHRA NO-108/1/2,                                         ",          ,AMBALA                                  ,133004,HARYANA             ,                    ,                  ,                              , ,'
```

it returns this result

```
['a','b','c','d','"x','x','2', 'hi']
```

But I want to have this one

```
['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' , '"x,x,2"' , 'hi']
```

how can do this in python

Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import shlex
lexer = shlex.shlex('a, b, c , d , "x,x,2" , hi')
lexer.whitespace += ','
print(list(lexer))
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '"x,x,2"', 'hi']
```

Here’s an updated solution for updated task:

```py
x = 'Outward   ,Supply , ,Tax Invoice ,IN9195212470,31/12/2019,VPS AGRO & AUTO PVT LTD ,311954,06AAACV9344F1ZA ,"VILLAGE KHANPUR KOLIAN, N.H. 1 ",6 K.M. FRO,KURUKSHETRA   ,HARYANA ,136131,VPS AGRO & AUTO PVT LTD ,311954,"VILLAGE KHANPUR KOLIAN, N.H. 1",6 K.M. FRO,KURUKSHETRA                             ,HARYANA             ,136131,503675,SM VAL. GENUINE DIESEL ENG. OIL 1/9 L   ,27101980,360,LTR,58204.04,9,5238.36,9,5238.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,68680.76,                    ,                    ,                              ,          ,          ,,               ,          ,06AAACW0287A1ZR   ,VALVOLINE CUMMINS PVT LTD-AMBALA        ,"KHASHRA NO-108/1/2,                                         ",          ,AMBALA                                  ,133004,HARYANA             ,                    ,                  ,                              , ,'


import shlex
lexer = shlex.shlex(x)
lexer.whitespace = ','
lexer.whitespace_split = True
print([cell.strip() for cell in lexer])
```

Result:

```
['Outward', 'Supply', '', 'Tax Invoice', 'IN9195212470', '31/12/2019', 'VPS AGRO & AUTO PVT LTD', '311954', '06AAACV9344F1ZA', '"VILLAGE KHANPUR KOLIAN, N.H. 1 "', '6 K.M. FRO', 'KURUKSHETRA', 'HARYANA', '136131', 'VPS AGRO & AUTO PVT LTD', '311954', '"VILLAGE KHANPUR KOLIAN, N.H. 1"', '6 K.M. FRO', 'KURUKSHETRA', 'HARYANA', '136131', '503675', 'SM VAL. GENUINE DIESEL ENG. OIL 1/9 L', '27101980', '360', 'LTR', '58204.04', '9', '5238.36', '9', '5238.36', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '68680.76', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '06AAACW0287A1ZR', 'VALVOLINE CUMMINS PVT LTD-AMBALA', '"KHASHRA NO-108/1/2,                                         "', '', 'AMBALA', '133004', 'HARYANA', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: I have post my real string

Comment: if you replace whitespace by comma then strip the items that should be the best answer

Comment: @Python logix, this is not how it works on StackOverflow. You can’t just change the task and say that the previous answers are wrong. Usually one accepts one of the answers and asks another question.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-ins that can achieve that without a lot of hacking to pre/post process the data.

- `shlex.split` would work to some extent with this example, but it's cheating, since it splits on spaces. If 2 elements are collated with only commas, this will fail.
- `ast.literal_eval` won't work since ... some items aren't literals
- `csv.reader` object *almost* does the trick with `[x.strip() for x in next(csv.reader([x]))]` but quotes aren't processed properly because there are spaces between them and commas.

But looping through each character with a simple state machine this can be done:

```
x = 'a, b, c , d , "x,x,2" , hi'

in_quote = False
current = []
output = []
for c in x:
    if in_quote:
        current.append(c)
        if c=='"':
            output.append("".join(current))
            current = []
            in_quote = False
        continue

    if c==",":
        output.append("".join(current))
        current = []
    elif c==" ":
        pass
    else:
        current.append(c)
        if c=='"':
            in_quote = True

output.append("".join(current))
```

result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '"x,x,2"', '', 'hi']
```

Just skip spaces, create a new element when comma is encountered, but have a flag if quote is encountered.

In the end, don't forget the last element being accumulated when end of string is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using only `split`. Please note it uses f strings (python 3.6+) but the same behaviour can still be achieved in older versions.
It is possible to achieve this without using regex as follows: I will comment the code for explanation:

```
# First split by double quote
x = x.split('"')
final_x = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    # We know that if the list element is even then it must be outside double quotes
    if i%2 == 0:
        # Split the list by commas and strip any whitespace
        x_element = x[i].split(',')
        x_element = [el.strip() for el in x_element]
        # extend the list
        final_x.extend(x_element)
    else:
        # This is an odd element of the list, therefore inside quotation.
        # put the string back into quotations
        x_element = f'"{x[i]}"'
        #append this to the final list
        final_x.append(x_element)
# filter out any white spaces left from the various splits         
final_x = [el for el in final_x if el !='']
```

Note the difference in appending the odd list elements and extending the even. This is because you are creating a new list with the split and we want to extend our output whilst for odd elements we want to add a new element to the list, hence we append.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex approach:

```
import regex as re

x = 'a, b, c , d , "x,x,2" , hi'

rx = re.compile(
    r"""
    "[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
    |
    \s*,\s*
    """, re.VERBOSE)
lst = rx.split(x)
print(lst)
```

This yields

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '"x,x,2"', 'hi']
```

Comment: Nice solution, its a bit pedantic but possibly adding a final `strip` so it gives the required output.

Comment: @B.C: Thanks for spotting it. It's better to compile it in the expression though - added `\s*` on both sides.

Comment: around 55 item will come in dict but it has 99 please check it

Comment: check my question "x" contain real string

Comment: i want to split it with ","  but not that comma which is coming in "x,x,s " Please check my x variable in question

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Comment: here is error what i am getting after run this code

Comment: lets chat do you want?

Comment: create a room for chat

Comment: You get an error because you import “re” while Jan is using non-standard “regex” library available from pip.